# Getting the same results (i.e. document) when calling .first or .last on a location query

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, activerecord, mongoid

I am using `Ruby on Rails` to create a `RESTful` web service. I am using `MongoDB` for the model and `Mongoid` as the ODM. I created the app using scaffold and everything works fine both from the browser and the ruby console. However I was doing some testing and noticed that if I call `first` or `last` as part of a location query, they return the same document.

## Here is a replication of the problem:

1. Created 10 event records.
   [image]
2. Verified calling `Model.last` and `Model.first` and everything worked fine.
   [image]
3. Verified records on array match by calling specific index, 0 and 9.
   [image]
4. Executed location query and included requests for the `last` and `first` records. The result was the same document. Verified records with specific index, and the results are correct.
   [image]

I (am new to ROR and) don't know why this is happening. Am I doing something wrong? Could it be a problem with Mongoid instead of Rails?

Thanks for any help. Cheers.

Comment: What happens if you do `.all.to_a`? What do you get as output?

Comment: I get everything just fine and event with venue10 shows on index 0 and event with venue1 on index 9.